# Adding a Dynamic Date as a Wordpress Function

Tags: wordpress, function, date, shortcode

I want to add a shortcode function in my Wordpress site that shows the date one week from now, two weeks from now and 3 days from now. I'd like to be able to add the shortcode [addoneweek] on pages where I need them.

Here is the code that I have, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
function addoneweek( $aow )
{
  return(<?php $now = new DateTime();
  echo $now->add(new DateInterval('P1W'))->format('m-d-Y');
  ?>)
}
add_shortcode( 'arttime', 'addoneweek');
```

Comment: add_shortcode('arttime', 'arttime');
function arttime() {

    $Today = date('d:m:y');

     // add 7 days to date
    $html .= Date('F j, Y', strtotime("+7 days")) . '<br/>';

    return $html;
}

Then I made one for each specified time in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in your current functions.php

```
add_shortcode('arttime', 'arttime');
function arttime() {

    $Today = date('d:m:y');

    // add 3 days to date
    $html = Date('d:m:y', strtotime("+3 days")) . '<br/>';

    // add 7 days to date
    $html .= Date('d:m:y', strtotime("+7 days")) . '<br/>';

    // add 14 days to date
    $html .= Date('d:m:y', strtotime("+14 days")) . '<br/>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: This works too, really, really, well.

As a side question, is there a way to exclude weekends in this calculation? I can't imaging there would be.....just curious...

Comment: Yes we can do that. And what ever answer is fit and good upvote correct that so other can take the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest reading over the [`add_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/add_shortcode) codex entry. It will explain how to use attributes/arguments.

Secondly, you are returning on your third line, which means that the `echo` on the fourth line is not going to run.

Thirdly, you also have a random opening `<?php` tag after your return, which you then try to close on your fifth line.

Fourth, and this is not really a big problem, but you should actually `return` your end result, instead of `echo`'ing it. `echo` will still output your request, but you're then essentially running an `echo` inside and `echo` when the shortcode runs.

This is what your function should look like:

```
function addoneweek()
{
  $now = new DateTime();
  return $now->add(new DateInterval('P1W'))->format('m-d-Y');
}
add_shortcode( 'arttime', 'addoneweek');
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It seems to work, but when I add the short code, it shows at the top of my page, not inline in the paragraph where I want it.  Why would that be?

Comment: I updated the answer a little earlier to use __return__ instead of __echo__. Double check that you’re also using return instead of echo. This is normally the result of echoing inside a short code.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

As a side question, is there a way to exclude weekends in this calculation? I can't imaging there would be.....just curious...